# Export to Xcode missing from Delphi XE2

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, delphi-xe2

I just downloaded and installed Delphi XE2. I opened a sample iOS firemonkey HD application (the one Lanusse shows on his videos) and theres no export to Xcode option.

Should I do something to be able to export code to xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at the Embarcadero FAQ on
[Cross-platform development for XE2](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Cross-Platform_Applications_Index) or the [Getting Started with iOS](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Getting_Started_with_iOS) FAQ

Comment: Maybe you could summarize here what the FAQ says on the topic.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, would it violate copyright if SO downloaded the pages referenced by html links contained within their content and hosted those pages on their own mirror, then modify the links to point to their own mirror, then sell advertising on the mirrored pages too? Sounds too good to be true, but I thought I'd suggest it.

Comment: Yes, it probably would, @Sam. Please direct suggestions to [meta].

Answer (score 0):

Look for the FireMonkey Prerequisites. Here is the direct link which addresses your topic: 
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Platform_Prerequisites