# I dont see "Export Xcode" in delphi xe2...?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, multiplatform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Export to Xcode missing from Delphi XE2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270830/export-to-xcode-missing-from-delphi-xe2)

i have delphi xe2 but don't see in tools menu 'export xcode' option .why?
Thanks for your notice...

Answer (score 2):

you need to add that menu option yourself - see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Development_Setup_for_iOS#Automating_DPR2XCODE_.28Optional_but_Recommended.29